# How to execute a callback when a QDialog is shown in PyQt4?

Tags: qt, events, pyqt, signals-slots, qdialog

I'd like to be able to execute a callback when a QDialog is shown in PyQt4, preferably via the signal/slot mechanism.  Looking at [the PyQt documentation on QDialog](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html), I can't find the correct signal to which to attach the slot that I want run.

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a signal to be emitted every time the dialog is shown, you could create a class like this:

```
class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    dialogShown = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super(Dialog, self).showEvent(event)
        self.dialogShown.emit()
```

and then use it like this:

```
    self.dialog = Dialog()
    self.dialog.dialogShown.connect(self.handleDialogShown)
```

Answer (score 2):

Would be fine in my opinion to override the [show](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#show) or [showEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showEvent) method and put your callbacks there.

```
class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def show(self):
        super(MyDialog, self).show()
        callbacks()
```

Comment: The `show()` slot isn't virtual, so `showEvent` might be the best choice (depends on the exact behaviour the OP wants, though). Also, the OP would prefer a signal/slot solution, so you could emit a custom `dialogShown` signal rather than invoking the callback directly.

Comment: @ekhumoro, could you elaborate more on how the `dialogShown` signal emission would work?  That sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @JuanCarlosCoto. I've added another answer to show what I mean.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes, I placed a generic callbacks without defining anything just to show where to place that logic. Maybe I should have defined a custom signal like you did in you answer, btw what does it means in the python context to not being virtual (regarding the show method)?

Comment: @DRC. A virtual method can also be called internally by Qt, whereas a non-virtual method like `show()` can only be called by Python code.